# How to generate new class objects with for loop

Tags: java

Hello so I am attempting to create an applet that has rectangles with student information inside of those rectangles. This is my code currently:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)//makes pretty pictures
{
        **Student grade = new Student();**  
    for(int a = 0; a<arr.length;a++){
        for(int b =0; b<arr[a].length;b++){         
            g.drawRect(165*a+5,55*b+5,150,50);
                **String grades = grade.toString();**
                **g.drawString(grades,160*a+5,60*b+5);**
        }
    }

    repaint();
}

class Student
{
private int test1, test2, test3, avg, ID;
public Student()
{
    test1=(int)(Math.random()*51+50);
    test2=(int)(Math.random()*51+50);
    test3=(int)(Math.random()*51+50);
    avg=(test1+test2+test3)/3;
    ID=(int)(Math.random()*90000+10000);
}
public int test1(){         return test1;}
public int test2(){         return test2;}
public int test3(){         return test3;}
public int avg(){           return avg;}
public int ID(){            return ID;}
public String toString(){   return "ID:"+ID+"  Avg: "+avg;}
}
```

In the paint method, I want to display the same number of the Student class as rectangles generated. However, it just prints for an infinite loop it seems like.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Perhaps you could reduce this to a [mcve], and also indent things consistently.

Comment: My apologies-- I didn't know if more code would be useful.

Comment: I just trimmed the code. If there is anything else I need to provide feel free to let me know. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Don't call [`repaint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint()) in your `paint` method.

`repaint()` means "This component needs to be repainted". If you call from `paint`, then every time it is painted, it gets another request to paint itself. So it will just keep on painting and painting.

Perhaps you don't realise you are overriding the [`paint(Graphics)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#paint(java.awt.Graphics)) method, which determines how a component is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the `Student` class?

Its `test1`, `test2` and `test3` fields are generated randomly at instanciation.

The relevant code is the following, found in the constructor of `Student` :

```
test1=(int)(Math.random()*51+50);
test2=(int)(Math.random()*51+50);
test3=(int)(Math.random()*51+50);
avg=(test1+test2+test3)/3;
ID=(int)(Math.random()*90000+10000);
```

`Math.random()` generates a random number between 0 and 1, so `Math.random()*51+50` will generate a random number between 50 (0*51 + 50) and 101 (1*51 + 50), and `Math.random()*90000+10000` a random number between 10000 and 100000.
The average obviously also change since it is based on the `test1`, `test2` and `test3` fields.